# Method filter for two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

There is a two-dimensional array. I have to get items without symbol 'o'. I can do this with a loop forEach. Is it possible to do the same thing with filter method?

1) Works fine

```
var array = [
  ['first1', 'second1', 'third1'],
  ['first2', 'second2', 'third2'],
  ['first3', 'second3', 'third3']
  ];
var filtered = [];

array.forEach(function (row) {
  row.forEach(function (item) {
    if(item.indexOf('o') === -1)
      filtered.push(item);
  })
});

console.log(filtered);
```

2) Does not work

```
var filtered = array.forEach(function (row) {
  row.filter(function (element) {
    return element.indexOf('o') === -1;
  })
});

console.log(filtered); //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything. Flatten the array first, and then filter:

```js
var array = [
  ['first1', 'second1', 'third1'],
  ['first2', 'second2', 'third2'],
  ['first3', 'second3', 'third3']
];

const filtered = array
  .flat()
  .filter(str => str.includes('o'));
console.log(filtered);
```